# Leibniz conjecture that geometry is a form of algebra

Tags: geometry, leibniz

> Hermann Grassmann (1840s) verified the Leibniz conjecture that geometry 1s a form of algebra, showing that the geometric figures themselves are algebraic entities, because they are subject to definite operations (such as taking the midpoint of the segment connecting any two given points) and their relevant properties are determined by equations involving such operations.
>
> Conceptual Mathematics by Lawvere and Schanuel

I am searching on the internet for this Leibniz conjecture but I can't find it anywhere. Could someone give me a reference?

Comment: There is a reference into G.Peano, *Calcolo geometrico secondo l'Ausdehnungslehre di Hermann Grassmann* (1888) (Preface) to: L' *Mth.Schr.* (1849), tome II, page 17 and tome V, page 133.

Answer (score 3):

In  his essay in Antognazza's volume ('18), Probst notes that

> Leibniz wanted to transform geometry into a pure doctrine of magnitudes without any direct relation to geometric objects. (p. 216).

Leibniz's work was a departure from the strictly geometric style of such predecessors as Barrow. Leibniz thought this was too hard, and sought to replace it by an algebraic formalism. The result was the Leibnizian calculus, where "blind calculation" achieves the results that were earlier only available through deep reflection and concentration on figures. Lawvere and Schanuel may be a bit cavalier here, since Leibniz envisioned this for transcendental curves as well, whereas what they are describing in Grassmann's name sounds purely algebraic.

There is a closely related comment in *New Essays*:

> On the topics and in circumstances where our senses are not much engaged, our thoughts
> are for the most part what we might call blind (in Latin I call them cogitationes caecas).
> I mean that they are empty of perception and sensibility, and consist in the wholly
> unaided use of symbols, as happens with those who calculate algebraically with only
> intermittent attention to the geometrical figures which are being dealt with.

This is quoted in Leduc ('14).